# How to use window functions in PySpark?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

I'm trying to use some windows functions (`ntile` and `percentRank`) for a data frame but I don't know how to use them.

Can anyone help me with this please? In the [Python API documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=ntile#pyspark.sql.functions.ntile) there are no examples about it.

Specifically, I'm trying to get quantiles of a numeric field in my data frame.

I'm using spark 1.4.0.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To be able to use window function you have to create a window first. Definition is pretty much the same as for normal SQL it means you can define either order, partition or both. First lets create some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

keys = ["foo"] * 10 + ["bar"] * 10
values = np.hstack([np.random.normal(0, 1, 10), np.random.normal(10, 1, 100)])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
   {"k": k, "v": round(float(v), 3)} for k, v in zip(keys, values)])
```

Make sure you're using `HiveContext` (Spark < 2.0 only):

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

assert isinstance(sqlContext, HiveContext)
```

Create a window:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w =  Window.partitionBy(df.k).orderBy(df.v)
```

which is equivalent to

```
(PARTITION BY k ORDER BY v)
```

in SQL.

As a rule of thumb window definitions should always contain `PARTITION BY` clause otherwise Spark will move all data to a single partition. `ORDER BY` is required for some functions, while in different cases (typically aggregates) may be optional.

There are also two optional which can be used to define window span - `ROWS BETWEEN` and `RANGE BETWEEN`. These won't be useful for us in this particular scenario.

Finally we can use it for a query:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import percentRank, ntile

df.select(
    "k", "v",
    percentRank().over(w).alias("percent_rank"),
    ntile(3).over(w).alias("ntile3")
)
```

Note that `ntile` is not related in any way to the quantiles.