# How can we use a window function (example with dense_rank) with the dataframe API instead of SQL in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can the query below be written using the data frame API?

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT c1, c2, value, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY value ASC) as rank
   FROM tmp_view) x
WHERE x.rank <= 3
```

The relevant documentation can be found at

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.Window

and

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html?highlight=dense_rank

But I could not fully understand the way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question

Comment: @mazaneicha please consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer before you downvote. I spent serious time solving this and I believe others will benefit too. This is encouraged by stackoverflow.

Comment: And I tried to clearly formulated it as a question

Comment: Got it. Although there are numerous examples of using `WindowSpec` on the internet, including SO (for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857863/how-to-use-window-functions-in-pyspark) and Spark's own spark.org, I guess one more wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pandas as pd
from time import perf_counter

# get a spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('learn').getOrCreate()

# create dataset
schema = StructType([
    StructField('c1', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('c2', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('value', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
])
import random
data = [(random.choice(list('ABC')), random.choice(list('abc')), random.random()) for _ in range(100)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema).drop_duplicates()
df.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp_view')

# window function (SQL)
query ="""
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT c1, c2, value, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY value ASC) as rank
   FROM tmp_view) x
WHERE x.rank <= 3
"""
res = spark.sql(query).orderBy(['c1', 'rank'], ascending=True)
res.show()

# window function (dataframe API)
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("c1").orderBy('value')
res = df.withColumn('rank', f.dense_rank().over(w)).filter(f.col('rank')<=3).orderBy(['c1', 'rank'], ascending=True)
res.show()
```

The produced dataframes should look like

```
df.show(n=5, truncate=False)
                                                                                +---+---+-------------------+
|c1 |c2 |value              |
+---+---+-------------------+
|C  |a  |0.38262849793622566|
|B  |b  |0.4117068824287389 |
|C  |a  |0.2622908081454347 |
|A  |b  |0.5371458199115897 |
|B  |a  |0.18469916475187298|
+---+---+-------------------+
only showing top 5 rows

res.show(n=5, truncate=False)
                                                                                +---+---+--------------------+----+
|c1 |c2 |value               |rank|
+---+---+--------------------+----+
|A  |c  |0.005163400336233082|1   |
|A  |c  |0.005434604534087506|2   |
|A  |c  |0.025183426923212848|3   |
|B  |a  |0.02414753220919985 |1   |
|B  |b  |0.04950658758922166 |2   |
+---+---+--------------------+----+
only showing top 5 rows
```